# How to synchronize objects access in a WCF Service?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I am writing a real time calculation program. This program would need a lot of data to be held up in memory. I want to write some service function that holds the data in memory for quick access. I want the service to have below functions.

1. if client asks for some data that is not in memory, load these data into memory from database, and send to client. The client needs to wait during this period.
2. If two clients ask for the same data, then if the data is being loaded by service in request to one client, then the service should know not to try to load again. How can I solve this concurrency issue?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I don't know how to synchronize objects with WCF. I know how to synchronize objects with multithreading, but I don't quite understand how WCF actually works around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may take a look at [caching in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx) applications. The [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) class is a good candidate for your requirements.